# Linux - How to change default application for text files with custom extensions?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-extension

I do some creative writing and use [PyRoom](http://pyroom.org) for most of my drafts. I want to save my drafts with a custom extension `story`(i.e. Persuasion.story) and associate `story` extension to PyRoom. I want to, however, open the other text streams with GEdit as usual.

Changing extension and setting PyRoom as default application for that extension doesn't work because it detects the mime type as plain text. So if I set PyRoom as the default application for opening Persuasion.story, it will open the other text files in PyRoom as well. Which I don't want.

I tried adding `text/story=pyroom.desktop` to my ~/.local/applications/mimeapps.list as well. It didn't work. The file still opens in GEdit.

How do I change the default application for a file with a certain extension?